# How to call cplex solver?

Tags: c++, call, solver, cplex

I am writing an algorithm in `c++` and I have a master and a sub problem. So I call cplex solver twice. The first time is when I call it solve the master problem and here is my code for that:

```
IloModel model_master(env);

definition of obj and constraints

IloCplex cplex_master(env);
cplex_master.extract(model_master);
cplex_master.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap,0.0001);
cplex_master.solve();
LB=cplex_master.getObjValue();
```

But it doesn't work! when I put `cout<<"1" << endl;` after `IloCplex cplex_master(env);` it does not print it.

Comment: and if you put the cout << "before cplex" << endl; just before the IloCplex cplex_master(env);  do you see that?  Are you getting an IloException?

Comment: Yes, I see that. The error is `Unhandled exception at 0x758cb9bc in For-Calling-Cplex.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: IloCplex::Exception at memory location 0x0026fb6c..`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function call in a try/catch block.

```
try {
   // ...
} catch (IloException &ex) {
   cerr << ex << endl;
}
```

You likely don't have the Ilm key set up on the machine you are trying to running cplex on.